# Is Phase shift limited between -90 to + 90?

Tags: power

In electrical engineering power systems I see several times a voltage or current in instantaneous form, as follows for example:

For the current"

**i(t) = I cos(ωt + 3π/4)**

And the voltage as follows:

**v(t) = V cos(ωt)**

However, it's known that the maximum phase shift is:

+90 degrees for a pure capacitor circuit where the current leads the voltage by 90 degrees phase shift.
-90 degrees for a pure inductor circuit where the current lags the voltage by 90 degrees phase shift.
So, how would the phase shift be more, since 3π/4 = 135 degrees?

Comment: More than 1 part is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an ideal first order circuit phase shift is limited to 90 degrees.

But In general phase shift is not limited to 90 degrees.  Second order circuits (some combination of two capacitors or inductors) can have up to 180 degrees shift.

An ideal circuit with just wires driving a capacitor has 90 degrees shift between current and voltage.

But that ideal circuit doesn't really exist.  In any real circuit the wires have inductance, and now you have a second order circuit.

And if you increased the detail of the model even further to account for parasitic resistance/capacitance/inductance within the real parts it gets even worse.